# SVG gradient linked to by data URI

Tags: svg, uri, gradient

Is it possible to use a gradient in svg without specifying an id for it? I need to be able to dynamically create potentially many gradients with javacsript, so I'd rather not have a counter going up to name them with.  Just seems sloppy to me.  I came up with this, but it doesn't render, any idea if this is possible or what I'm doing wrong?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

            <rect width = "100" height = "100" fill = 'url(data:image/svg+xml;

            <linearGradient x1="0%" y1="50%" x2="100%" y2="50%">
                <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255);stop-opacity:1;"></stop>
                <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,0);stop-opacity:1;"></stop>
            </linearGradient>

            )'></rect>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do.  I don't want to have to keep track of the id of the gradient, I want to specify the gradient for each shape. And data uri is not fictional syntax, I just don't know why it's not working in this case.

Comment: Why? Is url(#id) the only way url() can be formatted with svgs then?

Comment: I suppose, in theory, that ought to work, since data URIs work for `xlink:href` and both that and "url()" are defined to take an IRI reference.  Unfortunately the browsers only support data URLs for 'xlink:href'.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually get this to work if you format everything correctly.  The SVG has to be valid and URL encoded, and you still also need to use an id reference (in the form of a hash).

The following file works in FF and older (pre-Blink) Opera.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

    <rect width = "100" height = "100" fill = "url('data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%3E%3ClinearGradient%20x1=%220%25%22%20y1=%2250%25%22%20x2=%22100%25%22%20y2=%2250%25%22%20id=%22foo%22%3E%3Cstop%20offset=%220%25%22%20style=%22stop-color:rgb(255,255,255);stop-opacity:1;%22%3E%3C/stop%3E%3Cstop%20offset=%22100%25%22%20style=%22stop-color:rgb(0,0,0);stop-opacity:1;%22%3E%3C/stop%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3C/svg%3E#foo')"></rect>

</svg>
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/5erBw/4/)

(Thanks to Tab and Boris from the SVG WG for the help getting this working)

Comment: This works great in firefox, but not in chrome or safari, my main browser targets.

Comment: Yes. Pretty much just FF, as my answer states.  It's not the answer you are looking for, I'm sure, but there you go.  It seems unlikely webkit and IE will be supporting this in the near future, so you will have to find a different solution.